# Сочетание числительного и существительного

Tags: числительные

Правильно ли употребление формы слов: на выходных пограничники не пустили в Россию 22 волгоградградцев

Answer (score 1):

Нет, тут правильно будет сказать "не пустили в Россию 22 волгоградца". Ведь мы же не скажем "два волгоградцев". Соответственно, и "двадцать два волгоградца" прозвучит точно так же.
Вы просто проговаривайте фразы вслух и тогда не ошибетесь.

Answer (score 1):

После числительных два, три, четыре управляемое существительное ставится в родительном падеже е д и н с т в е н н о г о числа: ***два и более варианта, три и более трудных формы, четыре и более ценных предложения***, т.е. существительное ставится в зависимость от числительных два, три, четыре, а не от слова более (ср. возможность перестановки: два варианта и более).

***Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке
Розенталь Д.Э.***